# Как подключить вложенный контроллер в Laravel v5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Здравствуйте, я начал изучать Laravel, не могу никак понять, как мне распределить контроллеры header, footer и подключать их на каждой странице, как подключить их вид я разобрался, но я хочу чтобы информация($data) что передается на вид, шла от нужного контроллера. Такая реализация есть в opencart 2.x
Есть контроллер страницы в котором подключены контроллеры шапки и футера, и само подключение возвращает результат работы метода подключаемого класса. 
$data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

и вот эти данные уже импортировать в нужном виде. Надеюсь внятно обяснил в чем нужна помощь.

Comment: Вы хотите передавать одни и те же модели (например меню) в футер и хэдер и делать это для каждой страницы?

Comment: да, это я и хочу реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможность раздавать одни и те же коллекции для каждой страницы можно предоставить с помощью методов **view()->share()** или **view()->composer()**.

В случае с share вам нужно вызвать этот метод из сервис-провайдера. Он принимает два аргумента: имя переменной и ее значение:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Thread;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class AppServiceProvider
 * @package App\Providers
 *
 */
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('threadsCount', Thread::count());
    }
}
```

В случае с composer вам также необходимо вызвать его из сервис-провайдера. Это метод принимает имена вьюх, из которых будет доступна переменная и полное имя класса, который будет заниматься передачей значения. 
Сперва нужно зарегистрировать композер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Composers\ThreadComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class AppServiceProvider
 * @package App\Providers
 *
 */
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', ThreadComposer::class); //звезочка - все вьюхи
    }
}
```

Создаете ThreadComposer класс и метод compose в нем:

```
<?php

namespace App\Composers;

use App\Thread;
use Illuminate\View\View;

/**
 * Class ThreadComposer
 * @package App\Composers
 */
class ThreadComposer
{
    /**
     * @param View $view
     * @return int
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('threadsCount', Thread::count());
    }
}
```

Выберите наиболее привлекательный для вас способ и переменная $threadsCount будет доступна в представлении.
Подробнее об этом можно почитать в документации: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views